# Finding a specific index in a list

Tags: python, args

I'm trying to do a project where I need to track a robots final position *[0, 0]* after giving it limitless coordinates. **The coordinates can also be in negative.** For example north equals -10 is the same as south equals 10. So the coordinates are in the order of north, east, south, and west.
Example arguments: `track_robot(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`, `track_robot(20, 30, 10, 40)`, `track_robot(10, -10, -10, 10)`

This is my code:

```
# give as much coordinates as you want to the bot and return it's final position.
# north, east, south, west

def track_robot(*steps):
    pos = []
    north = 0
    east = 0
    south = 0
    west = 0
    for coord in steps:
        if steps.index(coord) % 2 == 0:
            if steps.index(coord) % 4 == 0:
                if coord < 0:
                    south += coord
                else:
                    north += coord
            else:
                if coord < 0:
                    north += abs(coord)
                else:
                    south -= coord
        else:
```

I managed to handle the y axis so north and south using their index values in the `*steps` variable, but couldn't seem to come up with an idea how to do it for the x axis(east and west). I got stuck at the end of my code. Can you please help me?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How do you know which one of the params you input is N S E or W? Are they positional? If not what is the logic to assign a number to a direction?

Comment: `f steps.index(coord) % 2 == 0` index() returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of the value.  This could lead to unexpected results if coord appears more than once.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that N and S are always at indexes that are divisible by 2, so I used that info to get if the next coordinate is north or south.

Comment: I think what John is saying is that if you have a repeated value, as in:  track_robot(10, -10, -10, 10)  ; when you call steps.index(coord) you will get always the position of the first equal value. Therefore, if you have 10 for north (index=0) and east (index=1) steps.index(coord) will think you are saying 0 and your algorithm will think you are always saying 'north'. You can check writing: track_robot(10, -10, -10, 10) and later [steps.index(coord) for coord in steps] - it returns "[0, 1, 1, 0]" as indexes.

Comment: I suggest you to use a dictionary like: steps = {'north': [1,2,3,4], 'south': [4,5], east: ...} rather than a list. Then you can work individually for north steps, south ones, etc. If you want to keep the input as a list, you can get the len of the list, calculate then how many indexes for north, south, west and east you have and split them with logical indexing or other ways.

Comment: @RobertoT But that code will be in the `else:` section to `if steps.index(coord) % 2 == 0:` so, if the index is divisible by 2, then it should just run the code and then continue on with the next coordinate right?

Comment: Oh, I think you got me wrong. So for example in `track_robot(20, 30, 10, 40)`, 20 is for north, 30 for east, 10 for south and 40 for west

Comment: The issue is iterating over steps.index(coord) because it always return the index of the first same value in the list.

Comment: But I'm iterating over `coord in steps:`

Comment: So it should just go on to the next coordinate

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't say properly. You iterate over steps and later call steps.index(coord). The problem is if you have 2 values that are the same, steps.index(coord) returns you the first it finds. Try with steps = [10,10,-10,10] and  [steps.index(coord)  for coord in steps if steps.index(coord)% 2 == 0]. You set the condition % 2 == 0 to get north and south values so the outcome should be [0,2] but with that steps list you get: [0, 0, 2, 0]. That means your algorithm thinks you are saying 10 to the north, 10 to the north, 10 again north (-10 is south negative), 10 more north.

Comment: I highly recommend you to try a dictionary, it is much easier. Or implement another algorithm with logical indexing with is much more difficult. I'll show you an example later if I find enough time.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help I'll try that :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for looping and indexing, you can work with a list as a input and extract the 4 coordinates as 4 different arrays. The trick is the reshape function for numpy library.

```
import numpy as np

def track_robot(*steps):
    """
    Input: 'steps' is a list of numbers: coordinates N,E,S,W
    
    Returns 4 different arrays for N, E, S and W
    """
    # Convert list to array (numpy array)
    arr = np.asarray(steps)
    # Check array has same steps for the same coords (N,E,S,W)
    if len(arr) % 4 != 0:
        # Calculate how much coords left:
            # If length % 4 != 0, then length/4 has a decimal part.
            # If we get the integer part of the fraction we can know the 
            # next subgroup of coordinates we need. We multiply by 4 
            # and subtract the length so we calculated how many coord
            # we don't have (E, S and/or W).
        nzeros = 4*(int(len(arr)/4)+1)-len(arr)
        # Add the number of zeros (no-movement in previous coords)
        arr = np.pad(arr, (0, nzeros), 'constant')
    # Now, we reshape as a matrix 4xM, where M columns = len(arr)/4
    # and 4 rows, each one for each coordinate.
    arr = arr.reshape([int(len(arr)/4),4], order = 'F')
    # Now split columns
    
    north = arr[0]
    east = arr[1]
    south = arr[2]
    west = arr[3]
    return north,east,south,west
```

First, you have to convert the list to a numpy array. I assumed coordinates are always sorted the same: North, East, South, West, so we can reshape the array as a matrix of 4 rows and extract each row individually. But for using reshape function, the length of the array has to be % 4 == 0. Therefore, if it isn't, we have to fill it with zeros using the pad function. (zero = no-movement for that coordinate).

Try with:

```
   # 1 = North, 2 = East, 3 = South, 4 = West. Last steps for 
    # south and west are missing.
    track_robot(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2)
```

*If it was helpful consider to vote as the solution :)*

Comment: Hmm. I really found this code helpful. But there was something more I needed. I need to return the coordinates as two numbers(as in x and y). So, ex. if there are only 4 coordinates given and east = 10 and west = 10, then the x coordinate should be 0. Or if east = 10 and west = -10, then x coord should be 20. Is there a faster way of doing that or do I have to use if s?

Comment: It is really easy to find the differences along the axis. `y = north - south` and `y = east - weast` . Of course, you have to take in account the postive or negative values if you use these vectors for later code. Also, this way: `y = north - south` performs a element-wise difference if you want the final position then just sum all the elements of the array `np.sum()`. I hope this is what you were looking for ;) @Abdullah Bera Koksal